# How to remove all cells in a pyqt4 tablewidget?

Tags: python, pyqt4

Suppose I have a pyqt4 table widget, for example:

```
self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(3,4)
```

With `self.table.clear()` I can remove all contents of the table. However how can I delete all cells of the table, not only the content?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Alternatively, you can set the row and column counts:

```
self.table.setRowCount(0)
self.table.setColumnCount(0)
```

Comment: old answer, but if I do this or if I use removeRow, my RAM is not cleared. Each time I clear the table and import new data, the used memory grows. I thought (Py)Qt was clearing the memory by itself, deleting orphans.

Answer (score 4):

Haven't tried it, but you can try:

```
for i in reversed(range(self.table.rowCount())):
    self.table.removeRow(i)
```